# How to avoid littering one's Tex directories with intermediate files

Tags: latex, miktex, tex

From https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8603/how-not-to-auto-generate-aux-bak-files-in-latex-closed

> I use winedt. I prefer to only have .tex files, or just dvi, pdf files that I need. i don't need these other files. Anyone knows how to disable them? Coz too many files look really messy. Thank you. :)

There are several ways I can think of of achieving this, but maybe I haven't thought of the cleanest and easiest, and I want to have this question as a reference.

So what are the alternatives, and what drawbacks might they have?  Any platform (Miktex, Texlive, etc.).  Maybe nice to have one technique per answer

Comment: Why community wiki? There doesn't seem to be a need.

Comment: Because (i) it is not my question, I just copied it across from another site, and (ii) there are an awful lot of ways to solve this problem, because there are an awful lot of tex and latex build tools.  I'm not going choose a right answer, except in the unlikely case that someone posts a good survey of all the tools.

Answer (score 5):

There's a script out there called [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/). It basically runs latex enough times to get cross-referencing correct, *and* when used with the `-c` option, it cleans up the auxiliary files. It's included in TeXLive.

Comment: A lot of people say good things about `latexmk`.  Note though, that it doesn't try to handle non-Latex technologies: if you use Context, Xetex, or Eplain Tex, then it is not a whole lot of help.

Comment: there is no way to cleanup the files after a make without running it again.. :/

Answer (score 1):

I use `make` to build my latex documents (no, it is not as smart as `latexmk`, but it is installed on all the systems I encounter and all my colleagues have it, so I can distribute documents with a build system that way), and I always have `clean` and `cleaner` targets to remove stray latex droppings and editor backup files.

Comment: The most flexible, but one you will always be having to tweak.  I mostly use this for Latex docs.